# Magento: Interacting with multiple database tables in single admin module

Tags: php, magento

I am working with a module that fetches data from two database tables. This data should appear in my admin module. Can anyone provide me with a tutorial for this ??

Comment: are you speaking on datagrid ? i.e on row listings ?

Comment: yes, it should appear as a grid in admin section. actully, i need basic info. regarding how my model with work with both tables and what should be the content of config file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please proceed as follows :

You must locate following method in your adminhtml folder of module. and then collect the query and perform a join as follows :

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()
                   ->join(/*perform a join here...*/ );
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

After this youu can add more column based on the data eturned.

I hope you know how to join a table, else please comment so i can provide you examples for it.

### Update

Example of join in magento

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('order_item'=> sales_flat_order_item), 'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id', array('order_item.sku'));
```

Comment: I know simple SQL joins.. do we do it in some different way in magento?

Comment: its okay, let me know if you need further help in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of tutorials are available in internet for this. But anyway you can follow this link. [CLICK_ME](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) . This a module creator. You can build your own module and download it. This is the simplest way to understand magento module functionality. Just build your module, download it, analyze, wanna some change..? Again your build or edit ..Thats it..!

Comment: If you want learn Magento functionality then follow Alan storm articles. That is best articles I read ever..
1. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento
I suggest this for all Magento beginners..

Comment: Yes, i read it, you are right... They are indeed good and quite helpful. But here also, the example provided is using a single table.