# Join tables from different databases in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, join

I need to join 2 tables from 2 different databases in Magento. I tried to find answer on web but can't find anything useful.

Also, can I execute one SQL query on different databases from one resource?

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, we are not here to code for you. I recommend you read: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

`SELECT u1.* FROM database1.users u1 LEFT JOIN database2.users u2 ON u1.id=u2.id WHERE u2.id IS NOT NULL;`

http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/2-joining-mysql-tables-across-multiple-databases

Edit:
Perhaps some of these links off links are of use:
[Magento: Interacting with multiple database tables in single admin module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587499/magento-interacting-with-multiple-database-tables-in-single-admin-module)

Answer (score 1):

All join methods in `Zend_Db_Select` accept a specific schema as last parameter. That way, you can specify this value for joins to a different database.

```
$schema = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig('custom_setup')->dbname;
$select->joinLeft($name, $conditions, $columns, $schema);
```